# Handling simultaneous button presses in React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, multi-touch, touchablehighlight, pressable

Trying to handle simultaneous button presses in React Native in Android. So far got this code

```
export default function App() {
  function click1() {
    console.log("click1");
  }

  function click2() {
    console.log("clock2");
  }

  function click1Out() {
    console.log("click1Out");
  }

  function click2Out() {
    console.log("clock2Out");
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View onTouchStart={click1} onTouchEnd={click1Out}>
        <TouchableHighlight>
          <View style={styles.button}></View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      <View onTouchStart={click2} onTouchEnd={click2Out}>
        <TouchableHighlight>
          <View style={styles.button}></View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Works perfectly on iOS, doesn't on Android(Expo managed). After two days of googling(reddit, stackoverflow,medium etc.) got nowhere. Any idea why or how to make it work ?

Comment: try to check this resource: https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder `PanResponder` API, which gives more control over touch events. It allows you to track multiple touches and manage their states. You would need to create a `PanResponder` instance and handle the `onStartShouldSetPanResponder`, `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder`, `onPanResponderGrant`, and `onPanResponderRelease` events to manage simultaneous touches. this post can be useful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67979879/how-to-create-multiple-panresponders-in-react-native

Comment: @Utmost
Created two panResponder instances, still doesn't work (now not even on iOS).
` const panResponder1 = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        click1();
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        click1Out()
      },
    })
  ).current;`

Comment: Have you got any error or warning messages? and what exactly is not working?  can you debug and see its data step by step and debug if your variables are correct and have some data?

Comment: I get no error and to explain what i want to achive, when first button is pressed i want to be able to press second button, without canceling the first one. Using panResponder it doesnt work on Android neither iOS ( guess, I don't  know how to make it work). But what i realised (using just View onTouchStart, onTouchEnd) on Android, when first button is pressed, whole screen becoming responsive if i use second touch ( i keep firing first button function ). Tried to play with Views but without success.

Comment: Have you tried to use `panResponder` for each of your buttons? for each button something like this: `const panResponder1 = useRef( PanResponder.create({ onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true, onPanResponderGrant: () => console.log("CLICKED"), onPanResponderRelease: () => console.log("RELEASED"), }) ).current;` and then `{...panResponder1.panHandlers}` on your View element. if it does not work, then it is very difficult to suggest anything else. Hope that helps to find a solution